# DBCP Tomcat connection pool leak

Tags: java, tomcat

```
<Resource name="myConn" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10.:1521:mydb"
              username="username" password="password" maxActive="500" maxIdle="50"
              maxWait="-1" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"     logAbandoned="true" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
/>
```

I am trying to find out areas of the application where connections are NOT being closed. I added the removeAbandoned and logAbandoned clauses in my context file but if i check v$session on oracle it is still showing the same number of connections active even after 60 seconds. Is there something wrong in the configuration above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set `maxActive` to smaller value like 50 and then check if the configuration is working correctly. 
According to [the docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) the connections pool must running low to execute the check for abandoned connections:

> When available db connections run low
>   DBCP will recover and recycle any
>   abandoned dB connections it finds.

I would also changed the `removeAbandonedTimeout` to 20 so that you won't have to wait to long to check if the detector is working fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Which document are you refering to? I was looking at this document http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html but cant find that bit that you mentioned

Comment: sorry I forgot to link to the docs (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). I've corrected the answer.