# Tomcat 6 going down after reaching its maximum number of threads

Tags: multithreading, tomcat

Our Tomcat 6.0.29 goes down after reaching its maximum number of Threads. I would really appreciate any help with it because it is a production server.

Here is part of the catalina.log file:

```
INFO: Maximum number of threads (600) created for connector with address null and port 80
Mar 8, 2011 11:19:37 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause

INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-80
Mar 8, 2011 11:19:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop

INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 8, 2011 11:19:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload

INFO: Waiting for 8 instance(s) to be deallocated
```

Comment: Sounds like a better fit for http://ServerFault.com

Comment: Maybe have a shorter timeout on calling a thread dead and moving it back to the pool?

Answer (score 4):

Take a Thread Dump to see what is holding onto all your threads. The stacktrace for each thread will be an indication of your problem more then the catalina.out error was.

**Windows**

on the console window press `ctrl + break`

**Unix**

on the command line enter: `kill -3 <pid>`

These can be safely taken on a running production instance.

Comment: @mindas I see about 500 threads having the following lines at the top of their stacktrace: Does this mean there is some bug in tomcat  database connection pooling?

Comment: @mindas "http-80-412" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000047b54800 nid=0x991 in Object.wait() [0x00000000634ed000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaac3977fb8> (a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1104)
        - locked <0x00002aaac3977fb8> (a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
        at

Comment: @mindas org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your [Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html) is set to 500 or 600 threads. If each thread usually accesses a DB connection, do you have the dbcp pool set to the same amount or more?

You might also check your [dbcp pool configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087559/dbcp-tomcat-connection-pool-leak)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at swap memory and other resources. I had an experience where the memory usage of each thread was too high (bad app design), causing the server to become unresponsive. If this is the case (or simply to test) reduce the number of threads and see if it still happens.

Comment: Thanks Colin but I checked the swap memory usage and it is 0 because I have got enough ram on this machine. And I'm wondering why it takes the server down!!! because as far as I know when the number of thread exceeds it's max Tomcat would cache new requests till some threads become available.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace) a go.

Attach a probe on `org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina` class, `stopServer` methods. If that doesn't help, try finding any other shutdown hooks and attaching BTrace profiler to them.

You should be able to get the full stack trace pointing to whoever requested that shutdown.