# Datasource in jdbc connection pooling not returning connection

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc, jndi

I have a jsp web application. I'm using jdbc connection pooling to use mysql database located at the server side. My web application hangs sometimes, when i checked debugging i found that it hangs at ds.getConnection(); It does not return any exception/error. Browser will be simply in loading state. I have included my DBConnection class which i use to create dadasource and getconnection from datasource.I'm calling getConnection(); method to get connection from pool. I have called closeConnection(); method in all jsp finally block to close connection. So i assume that the connection will be returned to pool once i close the connection

```
public class DBConnection {

public static Connection con = null;
public static String user_id = null;
public static DataSource ds = null;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return con;
}

static {
    con = establishConnection();
}

public static void closeConnection() {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            if (!con.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Context.xml

```
<Context path="/KnestAdmin">
     <Resource name="dbconn" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
            username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobitute_lms_data?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
</Context>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>dbconn</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Example servlet to show how i use the connection

```
public class Category extends HttpServlet {

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    IST ist;
    PrintWriter out;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
    }

    public void connectToServer() throws SQLException, NamingException {
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ist = new IST();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        try {
            connectToServer();
            switch (request.getParameter("mode")) {
                case "checkAvailability": {
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String sql = "Select category_name from course_category where category_name='" + category_name + "'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (resultset_val.next()) {
                        out.print("exist");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "checkAvailability1": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String sql = "Select category_name from course_category where category_name='" + category_name + "' and category_id!='" + category_id + "'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (resultset_val.next()) {
                        out.print("exist");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "checkwarning": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String warning = "";
                    String sql_query = "select * from course where category_id='" + category_id + "' and status='Active'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql_query);
                    if (resultset_val.next()) {
                        warning = "yes";
                    }
                    String sql_query1 = "select * from assessment where category_id='" + category_id + "' and status='Active'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val1 = statement.executeQuery(sql_query1);
                    if (resultset_val1.next()) {
                        warning = "yes";
                    }
                    if (warning.equals("yes")) {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "active_inactive": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String status = request.getParameter("status");
                    String sql = "Update course_category set status='" + status + "',last_updated_user='" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "',last_updated_ts='" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "' where category_id='" + category_id + "'";
                    int i = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                    if (i > 0) {
                    }
                    connection.commit();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            try {
                response.setStatus(400);
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                if (!statement.isClosed()) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                DBConnection.closeConnection();
                connection=null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        try {
            connectToServer();
            switch (request.getParameter("mode")) {
                case "add": {
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String category_desc = request.getParameter("category_desc");
                    String status = request.getParameter("status");
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO course_category(category_name,category_desc,status,created_user,created_ts,last_updated_user,last_updated_ts) VALUES ('" + category_name + "',  '" + category_desc + "','" + status + "','" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "','" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')";
                    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                    connection.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case "edit": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String category_desc = request.getParameter("category_desc");
                    String sql = "update course_category set category_name='" + category_name + "',category_desc='" + category_desc + "',last_updated_user='" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "',last_updated_ts='" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "' where category_id='" + category_id + "'";
                    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                    connection.commit();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                if (ex instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
                    response.setStatus(1);
                }else{
                    response.setStatus(2);
                }
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                if (!statement.isClosed()) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                DBConnection.closeConnection();
                connection=null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show actual code. Just having `if (con != null) con.close()` somewhere in no way guarantees proper closing of connections when exceptions occur.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I have edited my question with proper code please check.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to [close the connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)

> Use a finally statement to close a pooled connection. The following finally block would appear after the try/catch block that applies to the code in which the pooled connection was used:
>
> ```
> try {
>      Connection con = 
>   ds.getConnection(username, password);
>      // ... code to use the pooled
>      // connection con
>  } catch (Exception ex {
>      // ... code to handle exceptions
>  } finally {
>      if (con != null) con.close();
>  }
> ```

Your datasource reached the maximum connection defined.

Comment: All statements and connections are closed properly.I already have this code @user7294900

Comment: It's probably a leak.see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087559/dbcp-tomcat-connection-pool-leak

Comment: Even if i increase max connection this happens.i checked whole app connections is closed properly. I'm only accessing one page of the web app @user7294900

Comment: @Vinod actually the link advice to lower maxActive

Comment: Better yet, use try-with-resources, it avoids the null checking boiler plate (in addition, the example you show won't even compile).

Comment: @user7294900 I have edited my question with proper code please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be one big race condition. Only one servlet instance is used for multiple requests. As a result, on concurrent requests, your current code can and will leak connections.

When concurrent requests are executed, each of them will create a connection and assign it to the same instance variable, so one or more connections will be lost and remain open. The use of that `DBConnection.getConnection`/`DBConnection.closeConnection` suggests that you are potentially leaking connections there as well.

Please stop using fields to keep your `connection` and `statement`, and make these local variables instead. Also consider using try-with-resources to properly close connections, and consider using a `DataSource` directly instead of using that (probably unnecessary) abstraction of `DBConnection`.

Comment: Whenever i call getConnection() method. the datasource will return a connection from pool because i have a line con = ds.getConnection(); So in case of concurrent users accessing web app. Each user will have their own instance of static class. isn't it? And each time when i close the connection that connection will be closed. Can you clearly explain me the problem?

Comment: @Vinod No they won't. They will all share the same class, so probably your code is leaking connections all over the place.